# Minimizing chrome app window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Running into some issues with windows in chrome packaged apps. In the docs it says windows have the function close() and minimize()

```
window.close(); //works fine
```

However, when I try to minimize I get this:

```
window.minimize(); //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'minimize'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After fiddling I figured it out:

```
chrome.app.window.current().minimize();
```

Works fine now